# Hierarchical Array Conversion to Flat Array

Tags: php, combinations

I've got an array

```
$array = array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array('bob','bill'),
    array(4,5,6,7) 
    //can have between 0 and 5 "rows"
);
```

I want to convert to an array that looks like this...

```
[1,bob,4, 1, bob, 5, 1, bob, 6, 1, bob, 7, 1, bill, 4 .... 3, bill, 7]
```

I was trying to write a recursive function for this which looks like...

```
function GetValues($array, $rowIndex, $valIndex, $values)
{
    if(!isset($array[$rowIndex]))
    {
        return $values;
    }
    if(!isset($array[$rowIndex][$valIndex]))
    {
        return GetValues($array,$rowIndex+1, 0, $values);
    }
    $values[] = $array[$rowIndex][$valIndex];

    return  GetValues($array,$rowIndex, $valIndex+1, $values);
}
```

which just ends up iterating the array normally (prints 1,2,3,bob,bill,4,5,6,7)

Comment: `$flatArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array('bob','bill'),
    array(4,5,6,7) 
);
function combinations($arrays) {
    $result[] = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $key => $values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($key => $value));
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }

    return $result;
}
$combinations_array = combinations($array);
$flat_string = '';
$flat_array = array();
foreach($combinations_array as $value){
        foreach($value as $v){
            $flat_string.=$v.',';
            $flat_array[]=$v;
        }
    }

echo rtrim($flat_string,',');
print_r($flat_array);
```

Out Put string:
     1,bob,4,1,bob,5,1,bob,6,1,bob,7,1,bill,4,1,bill,5,1,bill,6,1,bill,7,2,bob,4,2,bob,5,2,bob,6,2,bob,7,2,bill,4,2,bill,5,2,bill,6,2,bill,7,3,bob,4,3,bob,5,3,bob,6,3,bob,7,3,bill,4,3,bill,5,3,bill,6,3,bill,7

Output array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => bob
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
    [4] => bob
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 1
    [7] => bob
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 1
    [10] => bob
    [11] => 7
    [12] => 1
    [13] => bill
    [14] => 4
    [15] => 1
    [16] => bill
    [17] => 5
    [18] => 1
    [19] => bill
    [20] => 6
    [21] => 1
    [22] => bill
    [23] => 7
    [24] => 2
    [25] => bob
    [26] => 4
    [27] => 2
    [28] => bob
    [29] => 5
    [30] => 2
    [31] => bob
    [32] => 6
    [33] => 2
    [34] => bob
    [35] => 7
    [36] => 2
    [37] => bill
    [38] => 4
    [39] => 2
    [40] => bill
    [41] => 5
    [42] => 2
    [43] => bill
    [44] => 6
    [45] => 2
    [46] => bill
    [47] => 7
    [48] => 3
    [49] => bob
    [50] => 4
    [51] => 3
    [52] => bob
    [53] => 5
    [54] => 3
    [55] => bob
    [56] => 6
    [57] => 3
    [58] => bob
    [59] => 7
    [60] => 3
    [61] => bill
    [62] => 4
    [63] => 3
    [64] => bill
    [65] => 5
    [66] => 3
    [67] => bill
    [68] => 6
    [69] => 3
    [70] => bill
    [71] => 7
)
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Without an explanation, this page is less likely to help future researchers and is not a good candidate to close future questions.

Answer (score 0):

A problem you will likely have is not knowing how big the original array is. You can write it recursively by destroying the array. In this example, I shift the first element off the original array. Then, with each recursive call, I shift off another element. I use a for loop to go through the values and return what I've built.

```
function flatten($array)
{
    if(sizeof($array)==0) return null;
    $first = array_shift($array);
    $ret = array();
    foreach($first as $value)
    {
        $ret[] = $value;
        $sub = flatten($array);
        if($sub != null)
            $ret = array_merge($ret, $sub);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. The fact the array is destroyed wont be an issue, i can just copy it before calling the function

Comment: I didn't pass by reference in the function, so it will copy the array and destroy the copy. Technically, it will copy the whole array, then the array with one element missing, then that array with one element missing, etc...

Comment: Is it possible to have the function return an array as specified in the question? I tried rigging it up, but the blank string is a bit awkward

Comment: It prints "1,bob,4,5,6,7,bill,4,5,6,7,2,bob,4,5,6,7,bill,4,5,6,7,3,bob,4,5,6,7,bill,4,5,6,7,".

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was really close in my edit haha

Comment: I did a quick edit (untested) that makes it an array instead of a string.

Comment: @kainaw Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: It is complaining because the recursion returns null at one point. You could fix it by returning array(), but I instead checked to see if the return was null.

Comment: Actually, as I didnt notice initially and @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez pointed out.  This methodology does not work.  It doesnt "fall back" enough

Comment: Now the error is "Notice: Array to string conversion". kainaw, you are close to the solution.